# How do I include a VS Code snippet in a Flashpost payload?

Tags: rest, visual-studio-code, random-seed, vscode-snippets

I am using the Flashpost extension in VS Code to prototype REST API calls before I publish the endpoint. What steps do I need to take to configure VS Code so that I can insert a variable into my payload and have it generate a random string or UUID when it sends the payload?

I don't need to even know what it sent (I'll be able to see it at the destination), I just need it to be different every time without having to remember to manually change it each time.

I have tried adding $UUID and $UUID_V4 and variations like {$UUID} or {{$UUID}} or ${UUID} and some are passed along as text and some come across as "undefined" - I'm very new to VS Code (the mandate was "stop using Postman and start using VS Code + Flashpost by end of week") so I don't know how to tell whether this is my own inexperience with the tool and what's the limitations of what Flashpost allows.

Comment: where in the doc page do they mention you can use variables other than `$HOME`? create a feature request at the Flashpost repo

Comment: thanks, @rioV8, doing that now

Comment: This feature is now added in Flashpost version 1.1.77
https://github.com/subasraj/flashpost-support/blob/main/random-variables.md

Comment: docs: https://github.com/subasraj/flashpost-support/blob/main/random-variables.md